# Complex Measures: Decomposition

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Given a complex measure: $\mu:\Sigma\to\mathbb{C}$.

[image: Variation Measure]

Consider its decomposition into positive measures:
$$\mu=\Re_+\mu-\Re_-\mu+i\Im_+\mu-i\Im_-\mu=:\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha\mu_\alpha$$

> Does it split into disjoint regions: $\mu_\alpha(E)=|\mu|(E\cap A_\alpha)\quad(A_\alpha\cap A_\beta=\varnothing)$

Comment: @Dirk: But can one prove Hahn-Jordan without referring to Radon-Nikodym?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the Radon-Nikodym derivatives:
$$\mu_\alpha(E)=\int_Eu_\alpha\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$
They give rise to the constraints:
$$u_\alpha\geq0:\quad|u|=1\implies u_\alpha=\chi_{A_\alpha}$$

> So the above can only hold for: $\mathrm{im}u\subseteq\{1,i,-1,-i\}$

As an example when this fails consider:
$$\Omega:=[0,1]:\quad\mu(A):=\int_Ae^{it}\mathrm{d}t$$
*(This way it becomes clear since it takes other values, too.)*

Comment: I'm confused. If I take $i\mu$ where $\mu$ is Lebestue measure then there is a perfectly good complex decomposition.

Comment: @AlexR.: Yes, that is why one uses the phrase "in general" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Set $A$ to be the set on which $\mu$ is positive and $B$ the set on which its negative.

Comment: Perhaps more accurately, choose A the support of μ+ and B the support of μ-.

Comment: @Did: But how to define the support of a positive measure?

Comment: It's not as easy as just to say there is a measure positive and there negative - note its not a function of points but sets

Comment: Freeze: [The usual way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition).

Comment: @Did: The definition in the link is for Borel measures only...

Comment: @Freeze_S: Would you at least say which measures you're interested in? If you take $\mu_-$ to be -1 on a Vitali set, 0 elsewhere and $\mu_+$ to be the usual Lebesgue measure then you'll run into serious problems.

Comment: @AlexR.: Ah no no ^^ I'm interested into complex measures and their total variation measure.

Comment: Until 16 hours ago the question explicitely specified that the measures were real, now revision 5 changed "real" for "complex". OP: Don't do this. (Unrelated: The drawing (added with revision 3 and still in the question) is absurd if the mesures are complex.)